# How Awful is My Decorator?

Tags: python

I recently created a @sequenceable decorator, that can be applied to any function that takes one argument, and causes it to automatically be applicable to any sequence. This is the code (Python 2.5):

```
def sequenceable(func):
    def newfunc(arg):
        if hasattr(arg, '__iter__'):
            if isinstance(arg, dict):
                return dict((k, func(v)) for k, v in arg.iteritems())
            else:
                return map(func, arg)
        else:
            return func(arg)
    return newfunc
```

In use:

```
@sequenceable
def unixtime(dt):
    return int(dt.strftime('%s'))

>>> unixtime(datetime.now())
1291318284
>>> unixtime([datetime.now(), datetime(2010, 12, 3)])
[1291318291, 1291352400]
>>> unixtime({'start': datetime.now(), 'end': datetime(2010, 12, 3)})
{'start': 1291318301, 'end': 1291352400}
```

My questions are:

- Is this a terrible idea, and why?
- Is this a possibly good idea, but has significant drawbacks as implemented?
- What are the potential pitfalls of
  using this code?
- Is there a builtin or library that
  already does what I'm doing?

Comment: Isn't this what `map` does?  And don't list comprehensions do this?  Why add a third technique to an already cluttered concept space?  Please explain how this improves over `map` and list comprehensions.

Comment: It doesn't improve over map(). It is a shorthand *for* map(). I agree map() probably doesn't need one, but a shorthand for iteritems() -> list comprehension -> dict() might have merit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This *is* a terrible idea. This is essentially loose typing. Duck-typing is as far as this 
stuff should be taken, IMO.

Consider this:

```
def pluralize(f):
    def on_seq(seq):
        return [f(x) for x in seq]
    def on_dict(d):
         return dict((k, f(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems())
    f.on_dict = on_dict
    f.on_seq = on_seq
    return f
```

Your example then becomes

```
@pluralize
def unixtime(dt):
    return int(dt.strftime('%s'))


unixtime.on_seq([datetime.now(), datetime(2010, 12, 3)])
unixtime.on_dict({'start': datetime.now(), 'end': datetime(2010, 12, 3)})
```

Doing it this way still requires the caller to know (to within duck-typing accuracy) what is being passed in and doesn't add any typechecking overhead to the actual function. It will also work with any dict-like object whereas your original solution depends on it being an actual subclass of `dict`.

Comment: I think you mean to have def unixtime() decorated by @pluralize. I tried out this example and it worked that way, accomplishes what I wanted in terms of extensibility, *and* make explicit what I was trying to do. Good show!

Comment: I totally agree on the types part, any function that takes unrelated types is broken. Though I wouldn't use a decorator here at all: `f.on_seq` is clearly `map` and if you want the same thing for dicts just define a similar function: `mapvalues = lambda f, d:dict(k,f(v) for k,v in d.iteritems())` .. which works for any function without any decoration.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you seem to be building logic into the wrong place. Why should `unixtime` know anything about sequencing? In some cases it would be a good idea (for performance or even semantics) but here it seems like you're adding extra features to unixtime that don't make sense in that context.

Better is just to use (say) a list comprehension:

```
[unixtime(x) for x in [datetime.now(), datetime(2010, 12, 3)]]
```

that way, you're using the proper Pythonic construct for applying the same thing to a sequence, and you're not polluting `unixtime` with ideas about sequences. You end up coupling logic (about sequencing) in places where the implementation should be free of that knowledge.

EDIT:
It basically comes down to coding style, reusability and maintainability. You want well partitioned code, so that when you're coding `unixtime` (say), you're concerned exclusively with converting to a `unixtime`. Then, if you're interested in sequences, you design functionality (or use built-in syntax) that is exclusively concerned with sequences. That makes it easier to think clearly about each operation, test, debug and reuse code. Think about it even in terms of the name: the original function is appropriately called `unixtime`, but your sequenced version might more appropriately be called `unixtime_sequence`, which is weird and suggests an unusual function.

Sometimes, of course, you break that rule. If (but only when) performance is an issue, you might combine functionality. But in general, partitioning things at first into clear parts leads to clear thinking, clear coding and easy reuse.

Comment: OK, so I appreciate this argument. I'm interested in knowing why this is a bad thing. Can you provide an example of where this would confuse the issue or blow up in my face?

Comment: @Brent: have added some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a huge fan of trying to help out callers too much. Python is expressive enough that it's not a big deal for the caller to handle the "listification". It's easy enough for a caller to write out the `dict` comprehension or `map` call.

As a Python programmer that's what I would expect to have to do since the Python standard library functions don't help me out this way. This idiom actually makes me a little more confused because now I have to try to remember what methods are "helpful" and which aren't.

Being too flexible is a minor gripe I have with the Python-based build tool [SCons](http://www.scons.org/). Its methods are all very accommodating. If you want to set some preprocessor defines you can give it a string, a list of strings, tuples, a dict, etc. It's very convenient but a bit overwhelming.

```
env = Environment(CPPDEFINES='xyz')                # -Dxyz
env = Environment(CPPDEFINES=[('B', 2), 'A'])      # -DB=2 -DA
env = Environment(CPPDEFINES={'B':2, 'A':None})    # -DA -DB=2
```

Comment: That was my first reaction, too; but see Brent's last example. His decorator "maps" across a dictionary, associating each key with the result of the function on the key's value. (I think...)

Comment: We have a lot of utilities that act on a piece of data, to unescape characters, scrub strings, convert dates, etc., and we end up doing a lot of maps, list comprehensions, and converting of dicts to iterables and back so I thought this might reduce the amount of excess code just to accomplish these frequent tasks.

Comment: @Dan That's correct. It's designed to be a shorthand for functions that are frequently mapped across data structures.

Comment: @Brent Newey: Here's the shorthand I prefer: `somefunc( [singleton] )` and `somefinc( iterable )`.  That way `somefunc` always works with an iterable.  Seems simpler to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not pythonic because:
 - in Python explicit is considered better than implicit
 - it is not the standard idiom like using builtin map or a list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

```
@sequence
def distance(points):
    return sqrt(reduce(
        lambda a, b: a + b, 
        (a**2 for a in points),
        0))
```

And your decorator becomes useless. Your decorator can be applied only for a special cases, and if you'll have using it, you'll break one of Python Zen's rule: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it".

Comment: The decorator is only meant to operate on functions that take in scalar values. But I do understand the argument.